# gqip for VHDL comments does not work

Tags: formatting, comments

After I `set syntax=vhdl` and `set fo=tcq`, running `gqip` on the following paragraph does not work as expected:

```
-- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
-- tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
-- laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
```

becomes:

```
-- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, -- tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, -- laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
```

Interestingly, using the same comment in a C++ (.cpp) file works as expected. This behavior shouldn't be related to any plugins since I tried with `vim -u NONE`; vim version is 7.4. Any ideas what could be wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should tell Vim what a comment is using:

```
:set comments+=:--,b:--
```

Explanation:

- The `comments` option contains a comma separated list of strings that can start a comment line.
- `:--` specifies the comment string (`--` in that case) repeats at the start of each line.
- `b:--` specifies a blank (`<Space>`, `<Tab>` or`<EOL>`) is required after `--`.
- See [`:help format-comments`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#format-comments) for details.

I see you typed  `:set syntax=vhdl` manually. If this script is put in the `.vimrc` file, Vim will set this option for you whenever you enter `:set syntax=vhdl`:

```
augroup vhdlsyntax
   autocmd!
   autocmd Syntax vhdl 
      \ set formatoptions=tcq
      \     comments+=:--,b:--
augroup END
```

On the other hand, Vim actually can identify when a `.vhdl` file is been edited, but for some reason these options aren't (at least in this  case) properly set in [`$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/vhdl.vim`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/38df43bd13a2498cc96b3ddd9a20dd75126bd171/runtime/ftplugin/vhdl.vim#L18-L23). However you can fix this issue by adding the `FileType` event to the previous script, like this:

```
augroup vhdlsyntax
   autocmd!
   autocmd FileType,Syntax vhdl 
      \ set formatoptions=tcq
      \     comments+=:--,b:--
augroup END
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! Is there a specific reason the syntax definition (`set syntax=vhdl`) doesn't take care of this?

Comment: Vim doesn't take care of this because the lines that set these options are commented out in [`$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/vhdl.vim`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/38df43bd13a2498cc96b3ddd9a20dd75126bd171/runtime/ftplugin/vhdl.vim#L18-L23) and even if they were uncommented, they wouldn't work either. Maybe these lines are outdated.